# $refs returns undefined in vue js

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous

I'm having difficulty using the reference, `ref`, of a tag as it currently returns `null`. Parts of the code is shown below:

```
<input-layout v-if="edit" label="Status" class="" ref="statusSubtitle">
        <u-select v-model='item.status' :options="adStatus" :disable="disable" tabindex="14" class="" ref="itemStatusDropDown"/>
</input-layout>

mounted () {
    this.$nextTick(function (){
      console.log("222 " + this.$refs.itemStatusDropDown)
      console.log("333 ", this.$refs.statusSubtitle)
    })
  },
computed: {
  edit () {
        //return true
        return this.item.getId() != null
      },
}
```

Currently the console.logs inside the `mounted` hook return `undefined`.
The problem here is that what's in the `edit()` function is asynchronous, as a result the `v-if="edit"` is still false by the time the `mounted` hook gets triggered. I want to add a class property to the tags `<input-layout>` and `<u-select>` hence my thought process was to do:

```
this.$refs.statusSubtitle.class.value = "makeItGray"
this.$refs.itemStatusDropDown.class.value = "makeItGray"
```

However, since `this.$refs.statusSubtitle` and `this.$refs.itemStatusDropDown` return `undefined` I can't add the class properties.

How do I add a value to the class properties in this case? Maybe there is a work around that I'm not thinking of?

Note: If I force the `edit()` method to return `true` then `ref` is no longer undefined. But in this case, the `edit()` method is doing an asynchronous task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case I would watch the `edit` computed.

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    status: false
  },
  computed: {
    edit() {
      return this.status;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    edit: {
      immediate: true,
      handler() {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          if (this.$refs.myRef) {
            console.log(this.$refs.myRef);
            this.$refs.myRef.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="status = !status">toggle</button>
  <p v-if="edit" ref="myRef">{{ edit }}</p>
</div>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers